# Alternative Captcha Website?

Tags: captcha

I see lot of people (re)creating their own logic question lists for website form verification. Eg. "What is the opposite of down?" answer = "up"

Is there any website that provides simple logic question captchas and allows including them on my site? (So I don't have to build and maintain my own list)

EDIT:
Preferably Not using Flash or any other plugin.

Comment: do you want a webservice or just download a list of question and answers

Comment: Check Text CAPTCHA http://textcaptcha.com/

Comment: @Dan Either would be acceptable

Answer (score 0):

http://textcaptcha.com

This site provides a web service to generate textual CAPTCHAs based on simple logic questions.